# .NETMF TimerCallback with varying TimeSpans?

Tags: c#, timer, timespan

I'm trying to get a Timer to trigger twice a day, instead of a steady timespan.
I want to trigger the callback at say 07:00 and again at 16:00, then repeat the next day at 07:00.

For some reason it's eluding me, this doesn't seem that hard, but I'm thinking I have to build a new Timer each day and kill it and end of day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just have a timer that ticks every hour and then only respond to the events at 7:00 and 16:00?

```
var timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += TimerHandler;

void TimerHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
  if (hour != 7 && hour != 16) {
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes. Basically the poster does not want a TIMER but a SCHEDULER that can work on mroe busienss level schedules - which is not in the .NET framework. So, a regular timer + logic works, or a scheduling framework like quartz.net.

Comment: Yes, a scheduler is a better way to describe things. This is in .NETMF (Netduino) so I'll look into rolling my own (hashtable keyed on timestamp with Callback object seems reasonable)

Comment: Fair enough - in that case I'd either go with JaredPar's suggestion, or work out how long it is until the next time I need to run and set the timeout to that duration.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use a long running timer to achieve this?  If you're waiting to perform a specific task, it's probably a better idea to write a console application that does whatever you need.  You can then set up a scheduled task to run your application whenever you need; see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the main thread, instead of in the comments, it's .NETMF (Netduino)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a good idea to trigger it every hour and check in the callback if the needed functionality has to be performed. When later you decide to change the times or even change the amount of triggers per day it can be done one one location without recreating the timer.

E.g. pass a list to the timer (extended) class that keeps the times when to really doing something and check this list every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in this thread I decided to author a "scheduler" library for NETMF.  It is similar in implementation to the timer pattern, but is based on TimeDate to specify the event.

You can get the library at https://github.com/pelogical/mfschedule